# c++ map of vector in structure

Tags: c++, vector, dictionary, iterator

The program I want to do is an anagram finder
From a dictionary file and a string input, the function "anagrams" should return me a vector (one for each size from 1 to max) of vector of words found in the dictionary that match all the combination of sub-words possible with input as anagram
When I create the new dictionary with the function createdictionary, I put every anagram in a vector of string
However, when I want to check for these anagrams in my anagrams function, I don't know how to access it (line 74)
In uniqueAnagram, I have every sub-anagram possible, everything is ok, but using

```
  if (dict.words.find(it->second)){
    cout << dict.words.find(it->second)->second[0] << endl;
  }
```

in the loop (as a test to see if the expression actually write the right words) leads me to this error and I don't understand why:

> In function 'std::vector,  std::allocator >, std::allocator, > std::allocator > > >, std::allocator std::char_traits, std::allocator >, std::allocator std::char_traits, std::allocator > > > > > anagrams(const std::string&, const > Dictionary&, int)':|
>   error: could not convert 'dict->Dictionary::words.std::map<_Key, _Tp,
>   _Compare, _Alloc>::find [with _Key = std::basic_string, std::allocator >, _Tp =
>   std::vector,
>   std::allocator >, std::allocator, std::allocator > > >, _Compare =
>   std::less,
>   std::allocator > >, _Alloc = std::allocator

I've been stuck the last 10 hours on this and I can't take it anymore, I really don't know how to solve that issue
Thank for you help, you'd save me life

```
//anagrams.h
#ifndef ANAGRAMS_H_INCLUDED
#define ANAGRAMS_H_INCLUDED

#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

struct Dictionary{
  map<string, vector<string> > words;
};

Dictionary createdictionary(const string&);
vector<vector<string> > anagrams(const string&, const Dictionary&, int);

#endif // ANAGRAMS_H_INCLUDED

//anagrams.cpp
#include "anagrams.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

string sortString(string input);

Dictionary createdictionary(const string& filename){
    Dictionary dictionary;
    ifstream ifs;
    ifs.open(filename.c_str());
    string word;

    while (ifs >> word){
      string sortedWord = sortString(word);
      (dictionary.words[sortedWord]).push_back(word);
    }
  return dictionary;
}

string sortString(string input){
  vector<char> vectorWord(input.begin(), input.end());
  sort(vectorWord.begin(), vectorWord.end());
  string sortedInput(vectorWord.begin(), vectorWord.end());
  return sortedInput;
}


vector<vector<string> > anagrams(const string& input, const Dictionary& dict, int max){
  vector<vector<string> > anagrams;
  size_t n = input.length();
  for (int r = 0; r < max + 1; r++){
    vector<bool> v(n);
    fill(v.begin() + r, v.end(), true);
    map<string, string> uniqueAnagram;

    do {
      string word;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            if (!v[i]) {
                word = word + input[i];
            }
        }
        word = sortString(word);
        uniqueAnagram[word] = word;
    } while (next_permutation(v.begin(), v.end()));
    vector<string> tempAnagram;
    for(map<string, string>::iterator it = uniqueAnagram.begin(); it != uniqueAnagram.end(); it++){
      if (dict.words.find(it->second)){
        cout << dict.words.find(it->second)->second[0] << endl;
      }
    }
    sort(tempAnagram.begin(), tempAnagram.end());
    anagrams.push_back(tempAnagram);
  }


  vector<char> vectorWord(input.begin(), input.end());
  sort(vectorWord.begin(), vectorWord.end());
  string sortedWord(vectorWord.begin(), vectorWord.end());



//  cout << (dict.words.find(sortedWord)->second)[0] << endl;
  return anagrams;
}

//main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "anagrams.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string filename = "C:/dictionary.txt";
    Dictionary dictionary = createdictionary(filename);
    vector<vector<string> > anagram = anagrams("llohe", dictionary, 5);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The code you claim to be having problems with isn't even in your code sample.

Comment: Sorry i've been doing a lots of edits to try to fix it and I lost it
I'm working on a laptop without a mouse so it's a bit hard

Comment: Oops I thought I deleted it ... I used it for some tests.
I copied the rest of the error but I don't know how to write on a new line here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`map::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) returns an iterator, not a boolean. If the key wasn't found, it returns the map's past-the-end iterator. So instead of

```
if (dict.words.find(it->second))
```

you want

```
if (dict.words.find(it->second) != dict.words.end())
```

or

```
if (dict.words.count(it->second) != 0)
```

It would be more efficient to store the iterator so you don't need to find the key twice:

```
auto found = dict.words.find(it->second);
if (found != dict.words.end()) {
    cout << found->second[0] << endl;
}
```